# Solution $\chi$ of $\chi_k(x)=\chi_x(f_k(x))$ given $f_k$ bijective

Tags: functional-equations, semigroups, binary-operations

Given a family $\{ f_a \}_{a\in H}$ of bijective functions over a set $H$ I need to find a family of functions $\{ \chi_a \}_{a\in H}$ from $H$ to $H$ such that for every fixed $k$ in the family

$$\chi_k (k)=\chi_k(f_k(k))$$

And $\forall k,x \in H$

$$i) \,\, \chi_k(x)=\chi_x(f_k(x))$$

... or maybe we can use $\{ f_a \}_{a\in H}$ to define a binary operation $*_f$ on $H$  in this way:

$$a*_f x:= f_a (x)$$

and we must to find a binary operation $*_\chi$ on $H$ witht this property

$$ib) \,\, x *_\chi k= (k *_f x) *_\chi x$$

> 1-Only with this assumption and the associativity, is the binary operation $*_\chi$ unique?
>
> 2-Can the choice of $*_f$ (the family of bijective fucntion) "force"
>   $*_\chi$ to be the only solution of the equation?
>
> 3-If not why? There is some general theorem about the uniqueness of
>   the solution of these kind of equations?

Comment: What is $H?$ Do tell...

Comment: @IgorRivin oh sorry, $H$ is just a set and all the functions of $\{ f_a \}_{a\in H}$  are functions $f_a:H \rightarrow H$. Do you think I should put it in the question?

Comment: Yes, because, it is not at all obvious (well, it is there in small subsripts) that $H$ is the same as the index set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the following.

1. In general, the answer is negative. For instance, if $a*_f x=x$ then Condition (ib) transforms to 
   $x *_\chi k=  x *_\chi x$. Then for each function $g:H\to H$ a binary operation $*_\chi$ on $H$ 
   such that $x *_\chi k=g(x)$ for each elements $x,k\in H$ satisfies this condition.
2. If $|H|>1$ then the answer is negative, because each constant operation $*_\chi$ on $H$ satisfies Condition (ib).

Comment: and what about "non-trivial" solutions?

Comment: @MphLee I shall think about it when $*_\chi $ is a multiplication on a (abelian) group $H$, that is when $a*_f x:=ax$ for each $a,x\in H$. It seems that if $H=(\mathbb Z,+)$ then there is a non-trivial solution $x *_\chi y=GCD(x,y)$.

Comment: Tell me if I got what you said. If $(H,*_f)=(\mathbb Z,+)$ then $*_\chi$ is the greatest common divisor?

Comment: @MphLee Yes, it seems that in this case one of possible $*_\chi$ is the greatest common divisor.